# node: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, linux

```
node
node: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib

find /usr/lib -name libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
```

I appear to have libstdc++.so.6 installed and in my LD_LIBRARY_PATH however node still can't seem to see it. What am I doing wrong? This is on a server so sudo is not possible the node install is local in ~/.local/bin

Comment: If you have "node" in your dev dependencies, remove it:
`npm r node`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

I found another thread that indicated the file was in *the wrong directory*.

I copied it to `/usr/lib` and received *another error*.

I then found this in a thread that fixed the problem:

```
sudo apt-get install g++-multilib
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried following various suggestions found under related questions on stack overflow, all without success. Finally I discovered that the reason I was getting this error is that I was on a 32 bit Debian VM, and only 64 bit is supported. I spun up a 64 bit Ubuntu desktop VM using Vagrant and the problem did not occur there.